# Is there a to set index of a data array within this.setState?

Tags: react-native

so lets say i have the following data

```
data: [
        { key: 1, id: 1, uri: "", image:false },
        { key: 2, id: 2, uri: "", image:false },
        { key: 3, id: 3, uri: "", image:false },
        { key: 4, id: 4, uri: "", image:false }
      ]
```

I want to update the uri using `setState()`and so far I have come up with the following using React.

```
 `data: update(this.state.data, {1: {uri: {$set: result.uri}, image:{$set: true}}})`
```

however, instead of just having 1, I want to be able to pass in index, i know i can do this with if statements but im sure theres an easier and cleaner way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a copy of data, update it and then setState. For example:

copy

```
let newData = { ...this.state.data }
```

update

```
newData[0].uri = '';
newData[0].image = true
```

setState

```
this.setState({data: newData})
```